# Dos parentesis en una función confusa de Python

Tags: python, funciones

Soy nuevo en Python y encontré una función que lleva dos paréntesis una con argumento y otra sin argumento y no encuentro explicación alguna; que significa esto como debo usarla:

`return rutas(arguments)()`

El segmento anterior se encuentra en el archivo **main**.py de la aplicacion rutas

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__version__ = 'rutas 0.1.0'

def main():

    try:
        import os
        import sys

        from rutas import rutas

        HOME = os.path.expanduser('~/.rutas')
        if not os.path.exists(HOME):
            os.makedirs(HOME)

        arguments = rutas.docopt(rutas.__doc__, argv=sys.argv[1:], version=__version__)

        return rutas(arguments)()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stderr.write('\n')
```

Comment: hola por favor añade el ejemplo en el que lo estuvieras usando y que resultado esperas obtener para poder apoyarte mejor

Comment: hasta donde se las funciones en python se inician así def suma(): por lo que dudo que eso que muestras sea una función; salvo la mejor opinión de otro miembro de la comunidad

Comment: En efecto la Funcion se denota `funcion()` sin embargo esta es una función que parece tener doble comportamiento pues el paquete rutas es un paquete de interfaz CLI consola;

Comment: Faltaría ver el código de la función `rutas` para estar seguro, pero lo más probable es que retorne una función, por lo que la sintaxis es totalmente válida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy sencillo.

```
return rutas(arguments)()
```

En esta construcción, la llamada a la función `rutas(arguments)` devuelve **otro objeto de tipo función**.

Por lo tanto, el segundo paréntesis, es para llamar a la función devuelta.

Acá un ejemplo más sencillo que te va a ilustrar perfectamente lo que pasa:

```
def inc(cuanto):
   return lambda f(x): x + cuanto

print(inc(3)(3)) # imprimiría 6
```

Comment: Es correcto y se puede ver que la función del ejemplo existe una diferencia importante y es que en el caso de `return rutas(arguments)() ` no se si estoy en lo correcto el segundo paréntesis al no tener un argumento no exige un valor de retorno; en ese caso no me queda claro si `return` solo aplica la parte `rutas(arguments)`; como explicaríamos eso ?

Comment: El que una función no tenga argumentos no significa que no exija valor de retorno. El `return` no es obligatorio. Por defecto devuelve `none` si no se encuentra uno dentro de la funcion